# 'Application' doesn't exist in System.Windows namespace (in library project)

Tags: .net-standard-2.0, library-project

I'm working on `.net standard 2.0` library project for my solution.

It have to include this method:

```
public Task ShutdownAsync()
{
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Problem is it gives me an error:

> The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context

It also doesn't exist in `System.Windows`.

As answers to similar questions suggests I tried to add reference to `PresentationFramework`. But it isn't on the list.

Looks like it have something to do with the fact I'm doing it in a library project targeted at `.net standard 2.0`.

Is here any way to add proper reference to this project?

Comment: You cannot use WPF classes in a .netstandard library.  WPF is very much not standard, targeting .netstandard doesn't make any sense since you always need the desktop version of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net standard 2.0 was the problem.

This class is platform-specific so I should target .Net Platform instead.